# What port is a remote SQL Server 2005 running on?

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection

How do I find what port is my remote SQL Server 2005 running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server's default port is 1433. If you are unable to connect, you may have to make sure your firewall settings are correct.

Alternatively you can find out which port SQL Server is running by opening your command prompt: (Start > Run > CMD). Type "netstat" and hit enter, this will show you what you're looking for.

You could also check SQL Server's Error Log on the remote server to determine the port. [Here are some more intracate ways of determining the port](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/finding-the-port-number-for-a-particular-sql-server-instance/).

[Additional information about ports right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152834/default-port-for-sql-server).

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's modified, it's the default port 1433.