# Default SQL Server Port

Tags: sql-server, database, networking, port

I have a VB6 application that uses SQL server. It needs to access it through a LAN. Therefore I want to make an exception in firewall.

What is the default port of microsoft SQL server ?

(I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005)

Comment: something which is easily searchable. In fact it's the first hit if you copy your exact title into a search engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default port for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152834/default-port-for-sql-server)

Comment: @MitchWheat now this page is the first result on google ;-)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The default port of SQL server is **1433**.

Answer (score 18):

The default port 1433 is used when there is only one SQL Server named instance running on the computer.

When multiple SQL Server named instances are running, they run by default under a dynamic port (49152–65535). In this scenario, an application will connect to the SQL Server Browser service port (UDP 1434) to get the dynamic port and then connect to the dynamic port directly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access

Answer (score 9):

For Http Request Default Port number is 80

For Https Default Port Number is 443

For Sql Server Default Port Number is 1433

Answer (score 2):

The default port for SQL Server Database Engine is **1433**.

And as a best practice it should always be changed after the installation. 1433 is widely known which makes it vulnerable to attacks.