# Using mySQL Server (Xampp) and SQL Server on the same machine

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xampp

I have been using Xampp to test my website stuff and everything was working perfectly until I decided to install Microsoft SQL SERVER 2017 to do some data science stuff (school stuff).

Now I can still start Apache but I cant start MySQL. Here is the log :

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2017-11-17 13:40:05 33f8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-17 13:40:05 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.2 started; log sequence number 1835037
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13284 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I tried shutting down the SQL Server using SQL Server Management but I still can't connect MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL/MariaDB/Percona use different ports (and it doesn't sound like you've changed from the defaults), I doubt this is related to you installing SQL Server. SQL Server uses [port 1433](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214212/default-sql-server-port) and MySQL [port 3306](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html).

As for what *is* using that port, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199/2385479 helps us. There is a suggestion for the [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) Sysinternals application or the alternate suggestion of using netstat (such as `C:\> netstat -a -b -n`) which should give you some idea of what's using port 3306.

It seems to me you probably have another MySQL server installed which is conflicting with the port XAMPP is trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can change port of sql server or mysql server and dont forget to specify the port while accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

As in the log, when you installed the SQL Server it "reserverd" the same port that your MySQL was using

```
2017-11-17 13:40:06 13304 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
```

You can change the MySql port in the my.ini file, which can be acessed by the Xampp Control Panel, under "config".

Or, you can change de SQL Server Port, following this tutorial: https://www.syskit.com/blog/change-sql-server-port/

Comment: Just changed the SQL Server Port, it didn't solve the problem.