Connecting java to smarterasp.net database
I have this code
package org.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Main {

    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQL5113.site4now.net;databaseName=*********;";
    private static final String JDBC_USER = "*******";
    private static final String JDBC_PASSWORD = "********";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Load the JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD);
    
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database");
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error1: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error2: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

and i always get "Error1: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
what can i do to fix this
i downloaded the jdbc jar files and put it into libs and added implementation to my build.gradle but still the same thing happens
stack trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:15)


You don't need to use Class.forName - the JDBC_URL you give is enough.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78229693/1847378).
Either the driver no longer uses that classname or (more likely) you do not have the correct library in your classpath.  Can you detail what is in your Gradle configuration?

plugins {
id 'java'
}
group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
implementation files('libs/mssql-jdbc-12.6.1.jre11.jar')
}
test {
useJUnitPlatform()
}
i have this in my gradle config is there something wrong with it

try replacing implementation files('libs/mssql-jdbc-12.6.1.jre11.jar') with implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.6.1.jre11'.  This will retrieve the library reliably from a central repository rather that relying on a local file
